# The evenings vs evenings

Tags: grammar, prepositions

> I often go there in the evenings.

**OR**

> I often go there in evenings.

Which sentence from the above two is correct?

(Note: My book says "*in the evenings*" is correct.)

Answer (score 2):

'I often go there in **the** evenings' is the correct way to say/write it.